# Nested Attribute Form Validation Bugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, routes

I'm seeing an odd bug with a nested attribute form.  I have two models, **Parties**, and **Guests**.  Party has_many Guests, and Guest belongs_to Party.  I have a form that creates Guests through Party.

The bug I'm seeing is as follows:

- When I first visit the form page, everything loads but I can't submit data.  If I refresh the page as soon as it renders, then whatever I type in hits the database when I press submit.  I discovered that the submit button changes to its active state when you click on it but it never leaves it when it's not working.

Why do I have to refresh my page before the form will submit data?  I'd appreciate some help unraveling this one.  I'm not even sure which thread to start tugging on.

**party.rb**

```
class Party < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :event
  has_many :guests, inverse_of: :party
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guests, :reject_if => proc { |attribute| attribute[:last_name].blank? }
  validate :validate_nested_attributes

  def validate_nested_attributes
    guests.each do |guest|
      errors.add(:first_name, "first name cannot be blank") if guest.first_name.blank?
      errors.add(:email, "must be valid") if !email_is_valid(guest.email)
    end
  end

  def email_is_valid(email)
    email =~ /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  end

end
```

**guest.rb**

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :party
  belongs_to :event


end
```

**parties_controller.rb**

```
class PartiesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end  

  def new
    @event = Event.friendly.find(params[:event_id])
    @party = @event.parties.new
    10.times {@party.guests.build}
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.friendly.find(params[:event_id])
    @party = @event.parties.new(party_params)
    if @party.save
      redirect_to event_guests_path(@event)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  private

    def party_params
      params.require(:party).permit(:id, :party_name, guests_attributes: [:event_id, :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone])
    end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1"><h2>Create a New Invitation Party</h2></div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 well" id="guests">
    <ul>
      <% if @party.errors.any? %>
          <% @party.errors.each do |attribute, msg| %>
            <li><%= "#{attribute} #{msg}" if @party.errors[attribute].first == msg %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <%= form_for [@event, @party] do |f| %>
    </ul>

      <%= render :partial => 'guest_fields', :locals => { :f => f } %>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 pull-right">
    <%= f.submit "Create Party", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right", style: "margin-right: 10%;" %>
    <%= link_to "Back", event_guests_path(@event), class: "btn btn-danger pull-right", style: "margin-right: 5px;" %> 
  </div>


<% end %>
```

**_guest_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :guests do |ff| %>

  <%= ff.hidden_field :event_id, :value => @event.id %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <%= ff.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <%= ff.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <%= ff.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email Address", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <%= ff.text_field :phone, placeholder: "Phone Number", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Rails server log for the GET request**

```
Started GET "/events/2993Alexandro/parties/new" for -.-.-.- at 2016-10-11 23:00:56 +0000
Cannot render console from -.-.-.-! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PartiesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"2993Alexandro"}
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."path" = $1 ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["path", "2993Alexandro"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering parties/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered parties/_guest_fields.html.erb (9.7ms)
  Rendered parties/new.html.erb within layouts/application (15.9ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_left_bar.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 180ms (Views: 98.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Comment: Are you using turbolinks? When behavior differs between visiting a page by following a link to it, vs. refreshing the page -- or opening it in a new browser tab -- turbolinks is a top suspect.

Comment: `<%= form_for [@event, @party] do |f| %> </ul>` Why is your open-form tag half inside the `ul` ? Where is the matching end? A form is a block-level component - it should be fully contained within the outer block - not half in one tag and half in another.

Comment: Good catch.  Somebody answered it below and I think the typo may have been the culprit.  I also had the main /div inside of the form's end when it should have been outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <%= form_for [@event, @party] do |f| %> 
</ul>
```

Why is your open-form tag half inside the `ul` ? Where is the matching end? A form is a block-level component - it should be fully contained within the outer block - not half in one tag and half in another.

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but it will certainly fix your html. try something more like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1"><h2>Create a New Invitation Party</h2></div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 well" id="guests">
  <ul>
    <% if @party.errors.any? %>
        <% @party.errors.each do |attribute, msg| %>
          <li><%= "#{attribute} #{msg}" if @party.errors[attribute].first == msg %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <%= form_for [@event, @party] do |f| %>

    <%= render :partial => 'guest_fields', :locals => { :f => f } %>


    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 pull-right">
      <%= f.submit "Create Party", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right", style: "margin-right: 10%;" %>
      <%= link_to "Back", event_guests_path(@event), class: "btn btn-danger pull-right", style: "margin-right: 5px;" %> 
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think this was it.  The /ul wasn't doing anything obvious, but I had the form_for's end outside the main div.  When I fixed that the bug stopped happening.  I banged my head on this one for 2 hours and it was a dumb typo.

Comment: heh - they are frustrating, but ultimately the best kind of bugs (because once you find them, the solution is easy) :)

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope i can help

```
def new
@event = Event.friendly.find(params[:event_id])
@party = @event.parties.new(party_params)
10.times {@party.guests.build}
end
```